# change blogger outer-wrapper width

Tags: html, css, blogger

I have a blogger theme called minimal and can't seem to find outer-wrapper to make the width of the blog bigger.

This is where I think it should be (code below) so am I not seeing something? www.mountaintopchef.blogspot.com

If you need more info let me know, thanks so so much in advance

```
body#layout #navigation {
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999999;
}

body#layout #navigation-wrapper {
    width:40%;
    float:left;
}

body#layout #top-social {
    width:40%;
    float:right;
}

body#layout #widget-area .footerwidget {
    width:250px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

body#layout #widget-area .widget, body#layout #sidebar .widget {
    width:250px;
}

body#layout div#Header1:before {
    content: "This is a property of Themexpose.com";
}

body {
    color: #777;
    font-family: Lora;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 1.75;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    text-transform: none;
    background-color:#FFF;
}

p {
    font-size:16px;
    line-height:26px;
}

a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#cea525;
}

a:hover {
}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    font-family:"Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

.container {
    width:1030px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.container.sp_sidebar {
    overflow:hidden;
}

#main {
    width:100%;
}

.container.sp_sidebar #main {
    width:675px;
    margin-right:30px;
    float:left;
}

#sidebar {
    width:320px;
    float:right;
    margin-top: 8px;
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing you want to change the width of the container class?

Answer (score 0):

I would change

```
.container {
    width:1030px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

to whatever width you want

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change these values:

```
.container {
    width:1030px;
}

.container.sp_sidebar #main {
    width:675px;
}

#sidebar {
    width:320px;
}
```

Remember:
If you change `width:1030px;` to `width:1230px;` you probably want to also change `width:675px;` to `width:875px;`
Otherwise content will not be wider but you will get bigger margins